# Django Save Override Throwing Primary Duplicate Errors

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

So, I have a model called ScheduleItem

```
class ScheduleItem(models.Model):
      agreement = FK
      location = FK
      start = models.DateTimeField()
      end = models.DateTimeField()
      totalHours = DecimalField

      def get_total_hours(self):
            start = timedelta(hours=self.start.hour, minutes=self.start.minute)
            end = timedelta(hours=self.end.hour, minutes=self.end.minute)
            td = (end-start).seconds
            totalHours=Decimal(td/Decimal(60)/Decimal(60))
            return totalHours

     def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
          if self.pk == None:
              super(ScheduleItem,self).save(self,*args,**kwargs)
              self.refresh_from_db() # to access the datetime values, rather than unicode POST
              self.totalHours = self.get_total_hours()
          else:
              self.totalHours = self.get_total_hours()

          super(ScheduleItem,self).save(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

This throws PRIMARY key errors. I get duplicate entries with the second super(ScheduleItem,self). I cannot for the life of me figure out how to check for pk to access the datetime value and then save again within the save override method. I've tried moving things around, I've tried saving within the get_total_hours() function, with nothing but trouble.

I just want the object to be committed to the db so I can get the datetime objects and then calculate the total hours.

I'd rather not convert to datetime within the save function.

Does anyone have any tip or can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you have id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) defined in your model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not pass `self` to `save()`. You're calling `super().save()` as a bound method on an instance, so `self` is implicitly passed as the first argument. Change it to this:

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        super(ScheduleItem,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        self.refresh_from_db() # to access the datetime values, rather than unicode POST
        self.totalHours = self.get_total_hours()
    else:
        self.totalHours = self.get_total_hours()

    super(ScheduleItem,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

You get this weird behaviour because the first positional argument is `force_insert`, and the model instance evaluates to `True`. The second call to `super().save()` tries to force an insert with the same pk you previously saved.

Comment: Yes! That makes sense. I will go back and read through the docs to get a better grip on it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use: `self.pk is None`.

Comment: @allcaps Why? Is there a potential problem with == that I'm missing?

Comment: @Craig `is` checks if two variables are the same object, while `==` checks if they have the same value. It is considered best practice to use `is` for singleton objects such as `None` (as per [PEP 8 programming recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations))

Comment: I spent entirely too much time staring at my code, and this was the problem. I had `super().save(self)`